# Forwarding mail to different mail system in Postfix

Tags: email, postfix

I have an e-mail server powered by Postfix. Aside from traditional e-mail accounts on my server, I want to maintain some accounts whose only role is to forward all incoming mail to differnet address on different mail system.

For example. I own domain `example.com` and I set account with address `username@example.com` on my server. And I want this one account to forward all incoming messages to mailbox in different mail system, in domain that does not belong to me `username@stranger.net`.
I know, that i can add an entry in in my `virtual_alias_maps` lookup table.

```
username@example.com   username@stranger.net
```

But I'm worried that to deliver message, Postfix will use original envelope sender address. It's okay if sender is from domain example.com that belongs to me, but otherwise `stranger.net` server may classify this message as a spam.

Is there some way, to alter envelope sender on delivery ?

Are `smtp_generic_maps` ment for this ?

If so, is it okay, that my server sends an e-mail using specific envelope sender, and then something else in message being forwarded ?

How else to deal with such problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Your concern was valid because the existence of SPF checker. If

- you forward an email comes from a domain with proper SPF record
- your IP doesn't listed in their sender SPF record
- the receiver use SPF record as a factor to identifying spam

then yes, you may have error message SPF fail and the email end up in Spam Folder.

[SPF community acknowledge this problem](http://www.openspf.org/SRS), and they propose Sender Rewriting Scheme (SRS) to workaround this problem. Basically it will rewrite the original sender domain to your domain before forwarding it alias address. For postfix, you can use [postsrsd (Postfix Sender Rewriting Scheme daemon)](https://github.com/roehling/postsrsd) by roehling to implement SRS.

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to be well aware, in a situation like yours, setting the return path to something that you control, is definitely important. As to how to do that, it should be as easy as simply reinjecting the email into postfix with the modified return path.

You can look into how to make postfix deliver your email to this command:

```
| sendmail -f postmaster@example.com username@stranger.net
```

I am just not sure if you can do that in the `virtual_alias_maps` table.